# Error al resgistrar usuario en prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

Tengo un problema a la hora de registrar una cliente en mi web prestashop 1.6, y es que a la finalización de la compra, al registrar un nuevo cliente y pinchar el el botón guardar, aparece este mensaje

```
TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to save account Details: Error thrown: [object Object] Text status: error
```

Desconozco el porqué puede ser, me he informado un poco por internet y en este foro y decian que el fichero "Authenticatio.tpl" en url: baseUri se pusiera una ruta.

He probado y sigue apareciendo el error.

Agradezco toda ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Esta era la solución ya que actualicé a php7 ps 1.6 no está actualizado a php7 y tiene ciertas incompatibilidades. Esta es la solución en el archivo ObjectModel.php hay que buscar la función que valida el código postal o 'postCode' por esta:

```
// Checking for fields validity
        // Hack for postcode required for country which does not have postcodes
        if (!empty($value) || $value === '0' || ($field == 'postcode' && $value == '0')) {
           if (isset($data['validate']) && !call_user_func('Validate::'.$data['validate'],$value) && (!empty($value) || $data['required'])) {
            $errors[$field] = '<b>'.self::displayFieldName($field, get_class($this), $htmlentities).'</b> '.Tools::displayError('is invalid.');
                    } else {
                        if (isset($data['copy_post']) && !$data['copy_post']) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ($field == 'passwd') {
                            if ($value = Tools::getValue($field)) {
                                $this->{$field} = Tools::encrypt($value);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->{$field} = $value;
                        }
                    }
        }
```